# PushSharp iPhone push-notification doent work

Tags: cordova, pushsharp, apn

Im trying to send push to  IOS APN with `pushsharp nuget`.

```
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, applecert, ""), serviceSettings);
                    AppleNotification notif = new AppleNotification().ForDeviceToken(deviceToken)
                        .WithAlert(message)
                        .WithBadge(1)
                        .WithSound("default");
                    push.QueueNotification(notif);
                    //wait for queue to finish
                    push.StopAllServices(true);
```

It worked once ... now im keep getting this exception :

> You have selected the Development/Sandbox (Not production) server, yet
>   your Certificate does not appear to be the Development/Sandbox
>   certificate!  Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!

Help me please.

Comment: Are you testing for development mode or production mode?

Comment: Your code seems to be Ok. I bet it's has to be something wrong with your certificate. Try to regenerate it maybe with a password. I have two certificates (production and development) but I tell Pushsharp that both are production. Had some problems with sandbox...

Answer (score 0):

Apple has changed how they generate certificates, and the name in the certificate is now different, so there is no way to check if it is a Production or Sandbox certificate, which is what PushSharp used to do (in addition to verifying it was one of those two possibilities).

To work around this Apple change, without updating PushSharp, you can disable the certificate check with the correct constructor:

`ApplePushChannelSettings(false, applecert, "", disableCertificateCheck: true)`

Finally, you should check out the 3.x releases of PushSharp as this issue is fixed there, and generally it is a more stable release.  It's also where the HTTP/2 APNS provider development is going to happen.  PushSharp 2.x will very shortly be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It was the certificate ... :)
I misatkently exported the private key instead of the public key .
Now its on development mode and works . 
I'll update here hows going with production mode . 
thanks!